Как обновить токен в Apache Jmeter
В Apache Jmeter пишем нагрузлчный тест для апи, в первой Thread Group проходим авторизацию(чтобы токен не вызывался один раз). токен закидываем в переменную. и в новой Thread Group настраиваем сами условия для теста. Допустим нагрузочный тест должен идти 15 минут. но токен протухает через 5 минут. как обновить токен?

Так а что мешает проходить авторизацию в первой Thread Group раз в 5 минут минус пара секунд? Добавьте какой-нибудь Constant Timer или Flow Control Action Sampler  с паузой на 300 секунд
Только переменная не подойдет, нужна будет JMeter Property, "закидывать" нужно будет с помощью функции __setProperty(), а читать функцией __P()
Пример использования: Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups
